# How do I stop the map at just one world/globe?

Tags: openlayers-2, postgis, google-maps

I am working on a project to put google maps layer and adding our data layers on top of it. using openlayers and google maps layer with out layer of top of it

now the google layer has max resolution of 156543.0339 and 22 zoom levels, I can limit the zoom levels and max resolution etc but how do I stop the map at just one world/globe

i.e. I don't want it to scrolling off to another wrapped around world!

[image]

Please see this fiddle for example,  http://jsfiddle.net/eaJHn/5

Anyone !!! ?

Comment: what do you mean by "stop the map at just one world/globe"?.you should explain your problem properly maybe with a figure and you will get better answers. Welcome to GIS SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to setting wrapDateLine : false as mentioned by atlefren.  I found a way with restrictedExtent and pass it the bounds.

There is another way to attach listener to the openlayer map object and re-pan or re-cetner

due to popular demand here is the relevant snippet of code. However complete code can not be pasted as it spans 2 or 3 files, so see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/eaJHn/7/  for complete example

Rest of the answers on this questions are also very informative , as they all provide different info needed to create a proper google map with openlayers

```
var maxExtent = new OpenLayers.Bounds(-20037508, -20037508, 20037508, 20037508);
var restrictedExtent = maxExtent.clone();

var map = new OpenLayers.Map({
            div: "map",
            projection: proj4326,
            displayProjection: proj900913,
            maxExtent: maxExtent,
            restrictedExtent: restrictedExtent,
        });
```

Comment: Can you please decribe your solution? It is not clear from mere note "the I found a way with restrictedExtent and pass it the bounds". Possibly include your code and then accept your own answer! It is even [encouraged to do this!!!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17467/166308)

Comment: The restrictedExtent takes a bound parameter, you can pass it the world bound in spherical mercator, something similar to maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-20037508.34, -20037508.34,
                                     20037508.34, 20037508.34), hth

Comment: can you possibly modify the example http://jsfiddle.net/eaJHn/5/ to show this, and then accept your answer?

Comment: sure , here it is the updated version , now this map does not wrap after one world, http://jsfiddle.net/eaJHn/7/

Comment: great. Maybe you should also include the code in your answer, then it will be perfect :) I will then upvote (but notify me so that I know), you can accept your answer and others will also upvote you :-)

Comment: Sure I updated the question with code snippet and fiddle link

Comment: great, well done!

Answer (score 2):

OpenLayers.Layer.Google (which I assume you are using) has the property "[wrapDateLine](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.wrapDateLine)" set to true. This should be set to false, and as the [source](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/2.13/lib/OpenLayers/Layer/Google.js) says you should also set sphericalMercator to true.

So, something like:

```
var layer = new OpenLayer.Layer.Google("Google", {
    wrapDateLine: false,
    sphericalMercator: true
});
```

Comment: hi Thanks for the reply, it does not seems to work, maybe I am doing something different , please see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/eaJHn/5/

Answer (score 1):

Guessing from your description you are searching for a way to stop the user to zoom out at a certain zoom level. Am I right?

In the OpenLayers Wiki about [Configuring ZoomLevels](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/SettingZoomLevels) you find examples for doing that with the minZoomLevel option:

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map( $('map') );

var layer  = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google( "Google",
         { minZoomLevel: 3, maxZoomLevel: 8 });

// layer.numZoomLevels == 6
```

Though it can be a bit tricky it worked for me on a Google layer.

Comment: +1 This is exactly what I wanted to answer. And the fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/eaJHn/6/

Answer (score 0):

```
var maxExtent = new OpenLayers.Bounds(-20037508, -20037508, 20037508, 20037508);
var restrictedExtent = maxExtent.clone();

var map = new OpenLayers.Map({
            div: "map",
            projection: proj4326,
            displayProjection: proj900913,
            maxExtent: maxExtent,
            restrictedExtent: restrictedExtent,
        });
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS Stack Exchange!  The code may say it all, but I would recommend always providing a few words with it to provide readers with some context.