# Keep OpenLayers 3 map from going past the dateline

Tags: openlayers

I have an OL3 map that constantly repeats its self. I have contained the WMS layers, though the vector layers like to repeat. What is really important is keeping the user from panning into nowhere, i.e. Keeping the user from scrolling past the poles and dateline. I added an extent to the view but it still adds some map past the date line and poles. Any idea how to prevent this?

```
view: new ol.View({
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 8,
        minZoom:2,
        maxZoom: 13,
        extent: [-20037508.34, -20037508.34, 20037508.34, 20037508.34]

    })
```

Is my current code

Edit: The solutions from previous questions are all OpenLayers 2. OpenLayers 3 is a completely different framework that shares virtually nothing outside of the name.

Comment: What code do you currently have?

Comment: Added. I see that extent really just keeps the extent in view rather than actually bounding it to that view.

Comment: Might be a possible duplicate. Does this work?: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60625/how-do-i-stop-the-map-at-just-one-world-globe

Comment: That is OL2, OL3 is completely different.

Comment: Perhaps remove the openlayers-2 tag? It would be clearer that it is not a duplicate, which it isn't.

Comment: I keep tagging it as generally openlayers and something keeps switching it to openlayers-2.

Comment: [tag:openlayers] is automatically mapped to [tag:openlayers-2] since it's a synonym, no one was purposely doing that. The correct tag is probably just [tag:openlayers-3], which is what you have now.

Comment: I assumed nobody was moving it but wasn't sure. Good to know going forward.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To turn off wrapping, set `wrapX` to false for each layer source.

The extent configured on the view restricts the center of the map. To restrict the extent, you can do something like

```
map.on('postrender', function() {
  var view = map.getView();
  var zoom = view.getZoom();
  var worldExtent = view.getProjection().getExtent();
  var extent = view.calculateExtent(map.getSize());
  if (!ol.extent.containsExtent(worldExtent, extent)) {
    var newExtent = ol.extent.getIntersection(extent, restrictedExtent);
    view.fit(newExtent, map.getSize());
  }
});
```

Also see https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/pull/2777 for a pull request that will allow doing this in a nicer way.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just using the bounds -180,75,180,-75 and accepting some dateline wrapping and not being able to use part of the north and south. EXTREMELY frustrating that there isn't a maxExtent in 3.10.1. Seems like a huge flaw. Map wrapping is ugly and so is having white space.